# Use GUI Editor in JUCE for Audio Plugins

Tags: user-interface, audio, plugins, vst, juce

JUCE's Projucer has integrated GUI Editor.
How can I use the GUI Editor to create GUI during Audio Plugin project creation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

- Select NewComponent.cpp (assuming you created is using "Add new GUI Component")
- Switch tabs (for example between Class and Subcomponents).

After these steps the "Add new component" functions become active.

I suspect that this is a bug in Projucer.